# Problem with uploading my sketch to my Arduino

Tags: arduino-leonardo, sketch, uploading

I chose the correct COM port but it won't upload.

Arduino: 1.8.3 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Leonardo"

```
Sketch uses 5252 bytes (18%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.
Global variables use 228 bytes (8%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2332 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2560 bytes.
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:160)
    at cc.arduino.UploaderUtils.upload(UploaderUtils.java:78)
    at processing.app.SketchController.upload(SketchController.java:713)
    at processing.app.SketchController.exportApplet(SketchController.java:686)
    at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportHandler.run(Editor.java:2149)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: processing.app.SerialException: Error touching serial port 'COM4'.
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:99)
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:144)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM4; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.
    at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:164)
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:93)
    ... 6 more
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
Exception in thread "Thread-124" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at cc.arduino.contributions.libraries.LibrariesIndexer.rescanLibraries(LibrariesIndexer.java:123)
    at cc.arduino.contributions.libraries.LibrariesIndexer.setLibrariesFolders(LibrariesIndexer.java:106)
    at processing.app.BaseNoGui.onBoardOrPortChange(BaseNoGui.java:682)
    at processing.app.Base.onBoardOrPortChange(Base.java:1297)
    at processing.app.Editor$DefaultExportHandler.run(Editor.java:2179)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: You tagged the question "Arduino-Nano" but said you have a Leonardo. Which is it?

Comment: did you find anything on this? i have a similar issue with an arduino nano 33 ble sense. it reccently rrived from pihut, but i can send it back if its the device. The drivers are uptodate. dont have another micro-usb cable that is used for data transfer, as most of the cables only support power. if anone found the solution, please update me !!

Comment: I had the same problem. try checking the crystal on your arduino

Answer (score 2):

This is the relevant bit in your error output:

```
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM4; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.
```

Is your Leonardo on COM4, or some other port? Does some other program have that port open?

Comment: Yes I now  it is a nono and not a Leonardo. I have trieyd with nono sketches and thers the same problem.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's a Leonardo or Nano -- the problem is that the Arduino application can't open COM4. Is the device you are programming on COM4? Is there any other application opening COM4?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any trivial solution from the error log, but you can try one or more of the following items:

- Unplug and replug the USB cable (to check if the connection is ok)
- Change your USB cable in another USB port from your computer
- Restart computer
- Change USB cable
- Try another Arduino (if you have two megas, or change to Uno if possible), just to check for uploading
- Reinstall Arduino

Comment: I install arduino on another device and same error happend. I haven't a other cabel or a arduino.

Comment: I found a new cabel ant it wont work. Weeks ago i have the same problem with an other nano. I think my  settings are incorect.

Comment: If you remove the Arduino, see you that COM4 is not in use anymore? And when you reconnect COM4 shows up again?

Comment: Yes. after remove com4 disappear. Plug in again an it shows me com 4

Comment: Than you can be sure the Arduino is on COM4. If your settings are incorrect, try to reinstall the IDE.